# after using swr doesn't even mean use redux-thunk or saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I am going to develop a panel with tables and many other components with reacted as spa and redux and other related stuff, I am going to use Swr(a cool package) for fetching remote data and cache it.

We use a hook (useSwr) to catch remote data1 and after data1 received, we dispatch simple action with payload data1 to store for persisting data1 and do redux things to let other components know.

And also consider if we want to do other things on other components base on received data1 we use useSelector(there are many other ways) to check if data1 is, then we use swr for fetch data2,data3 or any other related business requests.

question is:
doesn't even mean use thunk or saga anymore? because we handle async stuff in component with custom hook.

if you think we still need those for futuristic point of view, please give simple example for when saga or thunk will be need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation, I will use `swr` for all data fetching. If I need other components to know about the result, I will dispatch an action, if not, i'll keep the state clean.